# Using the Knockout hasFocus binding, how do I track the focus of a group of radio buttons?

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button, focus

I'm using knockout js, and I have some radio buttons that I have applied the `hasFocus` binding, so that I can track which control has the focus. But it doesn't work for radio buttons.

You can test what happens in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qttxfvqs/1/

The text box focus observable works fine, but the radio buttons don't. I get even stranger results if there are only 2 radio buttons.

Html:

```
<div><input type="text" data-bind="hasFocus: textFocus" /></div>

<div>    
    <label for="option1">
        <input type="radio" id="option1" name="options" value="option1" data-bind="hasFocus: radioFocus" checked />
        Option 1
    </label>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="option2">
        <input type="radio" id="option2" name="options" value="option2" data-bind="hasFocus: radioFocus" />
        Option 2
    </label>    
</div>

<div>
    <label for="option3">
        <input type="radio" id="option3" name="options" value="option3" data-bind="hasFocus: radioFocus" />
        Option 3
    </label>    
</div>

<hr />

<dl>
    <dt>Text box has focus</dt>
    <dd data-bind="text: textFocus">-</dd>

    <dt>Radio buttons have focus</dt>
    <dd data-bind="text: radioFocus">-</dd>
</dl>
```

js:

```
var m = function() {

    this.textFocus = ko.observable(true);
    this.radioFocus = ko.observable(false);

};

ko.applyBindings(new m());
```

How do I fix it? I want `radioFocus` to be true if any of the radio buttons have the focus, else false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that radio buttons are individual inputs; the group does not form a single input. They can't both have focus, and so the `hasFocus` binding fails. They must each bind against their own focus observable.

```
<div>    
    <label for="option1">
        <input type="radio" id="option1" name="options" value="option1" data-bind="hasFocus: radioFocus1" checked />
        Option 1
    </label>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="option2">
        <input type="radio" id="option2" name="options" value="option2" data-bind="hasFocus: radioFocus2" />
        Option 2
    </label>    
</div>


var m = function() {

    this.textFocus = ko.observable(true);
    this.radioFocus1 = ko.observable(false);
    this.radioFocus2 = ko.observable(false);

};
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tavgkher/).

If you want a value to be true if any of the radio buttons in a group are true, you will need a custom binding. How would you imagine this binding behaving if you set the bound value to true? Would the first input in the group become focused?

Comment: Using your answer, I actually created a computed observable to tie the individual focus states together: `ko.computed(function(){return self.radioFocus1() || self.radioFocus2(); }); Thanks.